# How do I use Webpack with ReactJS and NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

How do I use Webpack with ReactJS and NodeJS? My problem is both the server and client have source that needs to be transpiled through (babble et. al.) but the Webpack config file only has one output file.

What I need is my node app build and my client side app built and put in `build/`.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack won't compile your server code. You'll need to configure babel to transpile your server code when the server starts. Why do you need both server and client code in a /build/ directory? It's better to keep them separate.

Comment: Thanks. So how does one build both a Website and node.js app that required babble? Should I be using Webpack for the client and gulp for the server?